# Why is a certain series in a Hilbert module well defined?

Tags: banach-algebras, hilbert-modules

Suppose $(w_{\lambda})_{\lambda\in I}$ and $(\nu_{\lambda})_{\lambda\in I}$ ‎are orthonormal bases of a Hilbert module $E$ over the C*_algebra $\mathcal{A}$, such that $w_{\lambda}=u(\nu_{\lambda})$ where $u$ is a unitary operator on the dense submodule of $E$
. We define $U:E\to E$ $~$by $$U(x)=\sum_{\lambda} w_{\lambda}\langle \nu_{\lambda}‎,‎x\rangle,$$

Why is $U$ well defined?

Comment: Do you agree my changes, i.e., a little more explicit title; I have changed the tag because inner product exist only in Hilbert spaces, not Banach spaces.

Comment: If $w_\lambda$ is an orthonormal basis, what condition on coefficients $a_\lambda$ is needed in order for $\sum a_\lambda w_\lambda$ to converge?

Answer (score 0):

If you are taking about the convergence of the series, the coefficients are in $\ell_2$ because of Parseval's Identity. And the norms of the tails of your series are precisely the tails of Parseval's.